# Can't open Xmls with edge on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, xml, microsoft-edge

I cannot open XML files with Edge by double clicking on them, despite Edge being set as standard program for XMLs. The only thing that happens is that the cursor switches to the "wait cursor" for a split-second.
Inserting the filepath into the adress bar opens the XMLs just fine, even without the "file:///" prefix. Other programs (IE, Notepad, …) can open the files, both as standard app or via right-clicking and "open with …".

I've found this SO Question about opening *html* files in Edge via command line. Using the solution from the only answer, I can open the XMLs. Omitting the "file:///" prefix at least opens a tab with a Google search about the filepath.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155087/how-to-open-local-html-file-with-ms-edge

I don't think the cause is with the files, as I've been using Edge on for these XMLs with other PCs before. The well-formed-ness is certainly not the cause: Both Edge and IE open malformed XMLs, but fail to parse them properly. Grateful for any help with this rather weird issue.

I'm using the old Edge on Windows 10 Pro, Version 1909
Computer is a HP Pavilion x360 Convertible 15-dq1xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the new, chromium-based Edge resolved the issue: I can open Xmls by double-clicking if the standard app is set properly.

This is technically not a solution though, because the new Edge is a different piece of software: Edge can now be started by double-clicking the .exe and it's also installed into "C:\Program Files (x86)". Why "(x86)" though?! I suppose my original problem was rooted with how Edge was called to open files.

Well, I can't go back to the old Edge now and since Xmls look different with the chromium engine I'm going to revert back to IE for viewing Xmls.